# Complexity of calculating average across distributed network?

Tags: complexity-theory, distributed-systems, parallel-computing

What is the communication complexity of the **best known** algorithm for computing the average of a set of N*D numbers distributed across N nodes with D values per node? Assume you have full control over the network topology and protocol.

Comment: It's the same as a sum, which depends on the network topology.

Comment: If all you care about is communication, D>1 is equivalent to D=1.  N-1 partial sums must be sent regardless of topology.  You can rearrange the network to minimize time or diameter or degree, but you'll always need at least N-1 transmissions.  Every receiver can incorporate what it receives into its transmissions, so you'll never need more than N-1 transmissions.  WRT communication complexity, all reduction trees are equivalent.  I'm not sure what kind of answer you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could rely on the fact that, as @polygeric alluded to, the average of a set of numbers is the average of the averages over any partition of the original numbers. In other words, have each node compute the average of its $D$ numbers, send those $N$ averages somewhere and compute their averages.

How you do that efficiently will depend on the network topology and the communication protocol.

Comment: Right, my question is what the **best** known way to do that is.

Comment: That's unanswerable as it stands. As I said, that will depend on the network topology and the communication protocol. How are the nodes connected?  As a mesh, a hypercube, a butterfly? Can you do concurrent reads/exclusive writes? All these parameters make a significant difference.

Comment: Whichever topology gives the best communication complexity.

Comment: I meant that it's the same as the sum because (assuming you avoid overflow) it IS the sum, followed by a division.  I'm pretty sure an average of averages over ANY partition is not necessarily an average.  Do you have a proof of that?